# javascript Class only calling function once

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a problem with my code in which I have a `setinterval` loop that checks whether a variable `menuScreen == true` if it does then it creates a new object (or prototype) called gameMenu1 and sets itself to false again.

Under this in the loop is a try and catch statement that attempts to call the `gameMenu1.Draw();` function.

When I set `menuScreen` to = `true` it will run this draw function once and then just not run it again and i have no idea why.

**Javascript Code**:

```
//defining the canvas elements (initial setup)
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

//setting the menuScreen to true
var menuScreen = true;
var gameScreen = false;


//gamemenu class
var GameMenu = function () {
    // inserting a texture from files
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = "Assets/textures/TitleScreen.png";
};

GameMenu.prototype.Draw = function () {
    console.log('drawn to screen (menuscreen)')
    ctx.drawImage(this.img,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
};

setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    console.log(menuScreen)
    if (menuScreen == true) {
        var gameMenu1 = new GameMenu();
        menuScreen = false;
    }  
    try {
        gameMenu1.Draw();
    }
    catch(err) {

    }

}, 30);
```

**Cavas Element**:

`<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>`

Comment: there is no pastebin link. It is missing

Comment: Please provide an adequate part of code

Comment: oops sorry, must have forgot to add it. It is here http://pastebin.com/gCcLuBbD @BirjuShah

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have streamlined it, there is another 10 classes that were in the code but I made a new document containing only the uncomplete menu class, the main loop and parts of the init code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant parts of the code directly in the question.

Comment: okay, problem is that you need to indent the code by 8 lines for it to be recognised as code and with 50 lines or so of code i cant copy and pate it in, i need to indent each line separately for some reson, will give it a go but may take a while

Comment: paste code in answer box. Select all and press {} button.

Comment: oh didnt read that till finished the edit, sorry and thanks will remember that for the future @BirjuShah

Comment: You have an error in `prototype.Draw` (no semicolon) on first line.

Comment: You explicitly set menuscreen to false in the interval callback?

Comment: no error in console?

Comment: still doesnt work, I am not using strict mode and so javascript doesnt pay attention to them as much @SamuelAllan

Comment: @maleeb the console says                                                                 false testofstuff.html:34:2

true testofstuff.html:34:2
file:///C:/Users/Samuel/Desktop/Code/javaScript/Platformer/Assets/textures/TitleScreen.png
drawn to screen (menuscreen) testofstuff.html:27:2
false this shows that it is creating the prototype as it is reding from file and then drawing once but then it seems to not repeat that

Comment: var gameMenu1 -> define it outside the if statement. you cannot call it in try if it its defined in if statement.

Comment: i dont beleive it but that works, do you know why it happens to work like that, (as in why you cant define variables within if statements @maleeb

Comment: oh okay, wow come to think of it i dont think i have ever defined a variable within an if stement in javascript before and so never noticed it xD thanks alot! @maleeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats it,

```
setInterval(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.strokeRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    console.log(menuScreen)
    var gameMenu1;

    if (menuScreen == true) {
        gameMenu1 = new GameMenu();
        menuScreen = false;
    }  

    try {
        gameMenu1.Draw();
    } catch(err) {

    }

}, 30);
```

Comment: thank you but why does this work? as in why can you not define the variable from within the if statement

Comment: you can define it inside the if statement. but than it is unknown outside the if statement. its basic. :)

Comment: but the code posted as an answer and that in the question are exactly same for javascript interpreter. Even if you write the variable inside "if", it will still hoist it to the top anyways. @maleeb

Comment: they are not @BirjuShah on line 8 he has removed the var from infront of the 'gameMenu1' you technically dont even need to predefine the variable beforehand as long as you are not working in strict js. putting var defines the variable in the scope it was created (inside the if statement) removing the var makes the interpereter assume there is allready a variable called 'gameManu1' and so just creates it on a global level.

Comment: but if statement does not have scope. Only function has scope. You define it in if or outside if, it will always consider "var gameMenu1" at the top of function. This is what I am trying to say. Your code will not change anything functionally.@maleeb

Comment: @BirjuShah yeah ur right it will hoisting the variable. but after the second loop, if the setInterval fires again, than the gameMenu1 is no more defined. cuz menuScreen is false it will not define the gameMenu1.

Comment: In the OP code gameMenu1 will always be declared and defined (in all the iteration), it's just that it's value is undefined, and the case will remain same with your code. @maleeb

Answer (score 0):

The code will not run again because you set `menuscreen` to false.

Next time the interval will work, it will not go in the if condition to define `gameMenu1` and so it won't have access to it.

It also won't give error because it is in a try block.
Basically `gameMenu1` is `undefined`

Javascript interval has callback function as parameter and every time a function with fresh `socpe` is passed to it. It does not retain the scope from previous function.

Read more [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md)

Also check polyfill of setInterval [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to understand how setinterval is implemented.